# Deserialize only one object from JSON array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, deserialization

I get JSON response from API:

```
{
  "value": [{
    "some-field": "blah-blah",
    ...
  }]
}
```

There is always one object in the array so I don't want to store a pojo like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private List<InnerClass> value;
}
```

but like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
...
}
```

**How do I create custom deserializer for it?**

I have tried the following:

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Foo> {

    public CustomDeserializer(Class<Foo> clazz) {
        super(clazz);
    }

    public CustomDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Foo deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JacksonException {
 
        JsonNode jsonNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        String s = jsonNode.get("value").get(0).toString();
        Foo obj = new ObjectMapper().readValue(s, Foo.class);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

but there is some kind of circle issues and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from this line in you custom deserializer:

```
Foo obj = new ObjectMapper().readValue(s, Foo.class);
```

When you do it like this your `CustomDeserializer` is called a second time, but now with a json in different format and it can't handle it. To be more precise, it can't find the property named `value`. So you have two options for fixing it:

1. Create `Foo` and set fields manually

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Foo> {

    public CustomDeserializer(Class<Foo> clazz) {
        super(clazz);
    }

    public CustomDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Foo deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        JsonNode jsonNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        JsonNode valueNode = jsonNode.get("value").get(0);
        Foo obj = new Foo();
        obj.setField1(valueNode.get("field1").asText());
        obj.setField2(valueNode.get("field2").asText());
        return obj;
    }
}
```

2. To keep `CustomDeserializer` as is, you need to register your deserializer **only** with the `ObjectMapper` instance, which does the actual deserializing of the initial json and don't use annotations on `Foo` to specify deserializer.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Foo.class, new CustomDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

As a side note, if you choose second option, `Foo obj = new ObjectMapper().readValue(s, Foo.class);` - this line creates new instance of `ObjectMapper` every time you deserialize. It would be better to keep an instance of `ObjectMapper` as a static field, for example.

Comment: i have lots of fields so i dont like first option

but, are there a way to implement your second option in fasterxml annotations? so when i get the array from api feign would automatically use CustomDeserializer?

Comment: @yngGabone No, if you use annotations, every `ObjectMapper` instance will pick it up. You need to register this deserializer **only** with your main instance.